# Redirect traffic to different EC2 instances based on cookie (Nginx AWS)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

Im currently facing an issue with redirecting my website traffic to different separated EC2s Instances on AWS.
here is my situation
I have 2 different EC2 Instances running React App on them and I need to redirect my traffic based on Cookie which has been set initially.

I have read some documents and it was written that I need to create an Central server on another EC2 and redirect the traffic based on that.

here is the config what I have found online which needs to be set in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in my central EC2 server :

```
http {    
map $cookie_mycookie $frontend{
    default   reactApp1;
    value1    reactApp2;
    value2    reactApp3;
    # Add more mappings as needed
}

upstream reactApp1{
    server IP_of_EC2_Instance1;
}

upstream reactApp2{
    server IP_of_EC2_Instance2;
}

upstream reactApp3{
    server IP_of_EC2_Instance3;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://$frontend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
}
```

on AWS DNS records I have also set the IP address of this central server to my domain as an A record so when we go to the domain it needs to check with the cookie to redirect to the EC2s with the related Apps such as reactApp1 or reactApp2 or reactApp3 ... .

However the cookie is also set but I get `502 Bad Gateway` error from Nginx.

How can I manage to redirect my traffic to different EC2s ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on AWs, why don't you use an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) instead of "Central Server"?

The ALB will receive all incoming requests and will route the requests to your EC2 instances ("targets" in Load Balancer parlance). I you want to send (subsequent) requests to the same target you need "stickiness".

If I understand correctly your requirements you will need [application-based stickiness](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html#application-based-stickiness):

> Application-based stickiness gives you the flexibility to set your own criteria for client-target stickiness. When you enable application-based stickiness, the load balancer routes the first request to a target within the target group based on the chosen algorithm. The target is expected to set a custom application cookie that matches the cookie configured on the load balancer to enable stickiness. This custom cookie can include any of the cookie attributes required by the application.

Please note that using a Load Balancer implies additional costs (that should be in the same order of magnitude of the central server instance) but is more stable and easy to maintain that the central server instance.

Hope this helps.

Additional tip: since React application are "static" sites, hosting them on an S3 bucket is much cheaper, you may want to investigate this; please note that in this case load balancing and stickiness do not apply, but it should possible to use CloudFront and Lambda@Edge to select different origins (in this context origin is similar to target).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your message, I was researching more about ALB and Target groups thats why I reply to your answer late. so I have made two targeted groups each pointing to my different EC2 instance and I have created an Application Load Balancer and I made some rules related to my application cookie which is set (Node Express App) but I have another issue the rules doesnt apply and I get only redirected to the default method of my listener , basically my ALB just listens to its default method

Comment: so I made 2 rules except the default one and I have used conditions with HTTP header, I have set the name to cookie and values like this : mycookie_name=value OR mycookie_name=value; OR mycookie_name=value<space> but still not working and only it listens to its default method

Comment: also my node express app which sets the cookie the cookie attribute are sameSite="none" and secure="true" and domain=''mydomain.com"

Comment: Hi again , I have found this link to set cookies rule in the listener maybe can help others later `https://repost.aws/questions/QUpS601OgJSfObILWRa0j0Qw/cookie-based-routing-for-application-load-balancer` . Thanks for Guiding : )